# Two wow js on github

Tags: software, licensing

I see two wowjs distributors on the GitHub. The first is https://github.com/graingert/wow and the second is https://github.com/matthieua/WOW.

The first is under a license like [this one](https://github.com/graingert/WOW/blob/master/LICENSE) and [free of charge](https://wowjs.uk/). The second one have no license (seems proprietary) as far as I understand and [not free of charge](https://www.delac.io/wow/). I don't know how these two different ones are possible (it would be great to learn something about it).

Anyway, can I add / use free one to / in my commercial project? (I am a web template seller)

Thank you.

Comment: If I read correctly, one is licensed under MIT and the other dual-licensed under GPLv3 and a proprietary license.

Comment: I couldn't see anything like GPLv3. Can you specify where you see it?

Comment: https://github.com/matthieua/WOW#license "If you are creating an open source application under a license compatible with the GNU GPL license v3, you may use this project under the terms of the GPLv3."

Comment: Thanks but that's not my case. I don't create an open source app.

Comment: Matthieua's version [was MIT-licenced until Feb 2016](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/commit/68639b73f2467f2c66612a2fc23dfb0e505f5783). At that point because he is the copyright holder he could change the licence to GPL3 or commercial. graingert's version is based on the last version still MIT-licenced.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that these two Github projects are two forks of the same project. One is licensed under the MIT license while the other is dual-licensed under the GNU GPL and a proprietary license.

The MIT is a so-called "[weak copyleft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copyleft#Strong_and_weak_copyleft)" license. That means it is possible to take a work licensed under MIT, make changes, and release those changes under a different license like the GPL (as long as credit is given). The GPL, however, is a "strong copyleft" license. It does not permit to take a GPL work and re-release it under other license conditions.

> can I add / use this free one to /in my commercial project? (I am a web template seller)

That depends on a lot of details which would fall into the "individualized legal advise" category which this website does not and can not provide. Like whether you just use the software or create derivative works or whether you bundle it with other software it communicates with "at arms length" or combine it with other works to a single unit. A lot of questions regarding what you can and can not do with GPL-licensed software is explained in [the GPL FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html).